# Why does "&amp" sometimes show up on websites?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, special-characters

I have used Asp.net MVC to develop my website. I am facing some strange issue like character & showing as "&amp". I have tried to replace with & using jquery. But still it is causing. please give me solution, I found solution nothing in google regarding this.

//Adding code:

```
  if (childsdata.Results[j].Children.Count > 0 && State == "Open") {
       if (role == "Admin" && permissionLevel != "4") {
               childprojects.push({
                            label: '<b id ="' + childsdata.Results[j].ObjectID + '">' + childsdata.Results[j].Name + '<span class="projectsearch" title="' + childsdata.Results[j].Name + '" id="' + childsdata.Results[j].ObjectID + '"></span></b><small class="dark-gray"></small><span class="setting" title="' + childsdata.Results[j].Name + '" id="' + childsdata.Results[j].ObjectID + '"><span id="selected_prj_role" title="' + role + '"></span></span> <div class="cMenu" data-setting="exp.com" data-resource="google.com"></div>', id: childsdata.Results[j].ObjectID, children: [{}], isLeaf: true
                           });
                }
                else {
                            childprojects.push({
                                label: '<b id ="' + childsdata.Results[j].ObjectID + '">' + childsdata.Results[j].Name + '<span class="projectsearch" title="' + childsdata.Results[j].Name + '" id="' + childsdata.Results[j].ObjectID + '"><span id="selected_prj_role" title="' + role + '"></span></span></b>', id: childsdata.Results[j].ObjectID, children: [{}], isLeaf: true
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

If value of childsdata.Results[j].Name is 'process & governance' , then displaying as 'process "&amp" governance'.

Comment: If you haven't used `@Html.Raw()` or an mvc html string for the html in your variables, then any html will be displayed as text rather than as html

Comment: You need to post your code. Please review [ask] and update your question with an [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: How are you determining the value of `childsdata.Results[j].Name`? Are you breaking execution in the debugger and inspecting the values? Or are you assuming what the values are based on what you know about the data they're coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Pete is 100% correct here

> If you haven't used @Html.Raw() or an mvc html string for the html in your variables, then any html will be displayed as text rather than as html

Basically you're pulling strings from your database and for security reasons like avoiding XSS attacks your framework is html encoding all of your characters.

Comment: Well, not sure about 100%... it's not that it will be displayed as text, but rather it will be *encoded* into HTML.   So `var str= "a&b";  @str` will output `a&amp;b` while `@Html.Raw(str)` will output "a&b" (which is not valid HTML).  MVC4+ made it the default that it will encode, before that it would output as-is (and cause all sorts of merriment when the developer didn't know what they were doing...)

Comment: I am not using entity framework  nor pulling from database. I am using yui tree to render my data as tree structure and data is coming from Rally Web API. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: In case you are pulling data from an API with Javascript then the data can be html encoded. You could either encode it in the frontend or in the backend. But it is good to escape all meta characters and only use raw html in the desired places where the data comes from a trusted source.

Answer (score 1):

HTML uses the ampersand symbol (`&`) to escape other symbols that would otherwise have a meaning in HTML. For example, if you wanted your website to say `1 < 2`, you would need your HTML code to say `1 &lt; 2` because `&lt;` is the code for when you really want `<` to appear. (Normally a `<` is interpreted as opening an HTML tag.)

However, that means any time a `&` appears in HTML, the parsing/rendering engine is going to be looking for the characters to follow it to be some kind of code. So `&` itself needs to be escaped. `Ben & Jerry's` must be rendered as `Ben &amp; Jerry's` in HTML in order to appear correctly in the browser. (Sometimes browsers will intelligently fudge things a little if the characters following the ampersand aren't a valid code, but it's wisest to always escape content for the context that you're putting it in.

Most libraries that help with rendering HTML (like Razor or JQuery) will escape values automatically. The problem typically arises when things get double-escaped. Maybe a value was already set to `Ben &amp; Jerry's` because you expected to output it to HTML, and then you use `jQuery('.something').text(...)` to set the text of an element to that value. Then you'll end up with `Ben &amp;amp; Jerry's`, which will render in HTML as `Ben &amp; Jerry's`.

So you need to make sure that things are only ever escaped as they are being inserted into the code context where that escaping makes sense.

Comment: I am not using HTML directly, I am using jquery, yui tree and rally web api to render the api data as tree structure. not what is wrong in this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the text using InnerHTML.
This is what I was doing first

```
<h1 class="title">{{cloudbanner?.title}}</h1>
```

and this is what worked for me to avoid **&amp;**

```
<h1 class="title" [innerHTML]="cloudbanner?.title"></h1>
```

I hope this helps you. :)